# How can I do something as simple as setting text to a textview in a listview

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, textview

All Im getting is a nullpointer, makes no sense to me

```
    new Handler().post(new Runnable(){          
        @Override
        public void run(){
            cursorAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactDBHelper.listAll());

            View footer = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer,null);
            contactCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contactCounter);

            //This is where im getting a NullPointer
            contactCounter.setText("Hi");

            listView.addFooterView(footer);

            listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone spot what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to find the footer view on the wrong parent view.

At the moment the code you posted is trying to find the "contactCounter" on your base view, which is not what you want. You want to find the "contactCounter" view on your footer view.

Change this line:

```
contactCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.contactCounter);
```

to

```
contactCounter = (TextView)footer.findViewById(R.id.contactCounter);
```

And it should work as you want it to.

Comment: Holy C! Thank you a thousand times!